# Firebase change password of a user using a custom webpage

Tags: javascript, firebase

I am attempting to create a user management system and my users are from firebase auth, is there a way to change the users password from my webpage without authenticating? cause i want to reset their password to a default one this is when users forgot their password and don't have access to their emails.

This is the code for changing the current authenticated user but is their a way to not authenticate and just change the password?

```
let user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
let newPassword = getASecureRandomPassword();

user.updatePassword(newPassword).then(() => {
  // Update successful.
}, (error) => {
  // An error happened.
});
```

Comment: You cannot reset another user password from the front-end web sdk as that would mean anybody can reset anybody else's password. If you need to do it, you need to use admin-sdk where you won't need to authenticate as that user and can update their profile, reset their password etc server side.

Comment: Ok then the admin-sdk is the path to take, thanks

Answer (score 1):

The best way to change user's password is by resetting it. You may do this using the Firebase Admin SDK, see below:

```
// Admin SDK API to generate the password reset link.
const userEmail = 'user@example.com';
getAuth()
  .generatePasswordResetLink(userEmail, actionCodeSettings)
  .then((link) => {
    // Construct password reset email template, embed the link and send
    // using custom SMTP server.
    return sendCustomPasswordResetEmail(userEmail, displayName, link);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // Some error occurred.
  });
```

To generate a password reset link, provide the existing user’s email. After the link is generated, it can be inserted into the custom password reset email and then emailed to the corresponding user. See this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/email-action-links#generate_password_reset_email_link) for your reference.